# TypeConverter Attribute for Third Party Classes

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, typeconverter, sealed

When creating a class, a TypeConverter attribute can be applied to it s.t. using TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)) return the custom type converter.  For instance:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
public class Foo
{...}

public class FooConverter: TypeConverter
{...}

var tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)); //returns a FooConverter instance.
```

This works as long as the class is of our making.  But how would one provide a custom TypeConverter for a class which we cannot modify the source code?  For example, how would one provide a custom TypeConverter for the the System.Version class (which does not have one)?

Comment: I believe this is answered here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I have read this article prior to posting here, and I do not believe that it addresses my concern.  It's still a good article though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it at runtime. With these classes:

```
class MyConverter : TypeConverter
{
}

sealed class MyClass
{   
}
```

You can use:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(MyClass), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(MyConverter)));
```

Comment: Yep, that works.  It's unfortunate that this has to be done at runtime, but it's better than nothing.  Thanks for the help!